# Problem with responsivity of card in grid layout of css

Tags: html, css

[https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/VwXKKgG]

When viewed in mobile version, the width of the card exceeds the Content hr (horizontal line). What can be done so that it does not exceed the horizontal line? Do not go with the 5 fr or 1fr unit. I can manage the 1 fr or 5fr scene. But only problem is with the card that exceeds the hr line which is blue in color.

```css
.container-a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container-a span {
  background-color: #007bff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.container-a hr {
  width: 100%;
  color: #007bff;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.container-a .wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "blog-container blog-container blog-container blog-container blog-sidebar";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container-a .blog-container {
  grid-area: blog-container;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  min-width: 280px;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  height: 180px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FF7F50;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.container-a .blog-sidebar {
  grid-area: blog-sidebar;
}

.blog-sidebar .widgets {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.widgets img {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.blog-sidebar h3 {
  color: #007bff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px 0 2px 0;
  margin: -1px 0 -1px 0;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .container-a {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
  }
  .container-a span {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .container-a hr {
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
  .container-a {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .container-a .wrapper {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "blog-container" "blog-sidebar";
  }
  .card {
    min-width: 244px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container-a" aria-label="blog-content">
  <span>Content</span>
  
  <hr>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="blog-container">
      <div class="card">Card 1</div>
      <div class="card">Card 2</div>
      <div class="card">Card 3</div>
      <div class="card">Card 4</div>
      <div class="card">Card 5</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="blog-sidebar">
      <h3>Sidebar</h3>
      
      <div class="widgets">
        <div class="card">Card 1</div>
        <div class="card">Card 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see what you describe occurring at any screen size.

Comment: @isherwood i didn't get you!

Comment: I don't understand that comment, but you could probably eliminate the rule element and just use a border on the wrapper element.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the rule is always the same width as the card grid for me.

Comment: okay i understood. but let more answers come

Comment: Does this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctnk9.png) show the problem? If so, add the image to your post.

Comment: Yes, image showed the problem

Comment: @aplua no. when viewed in mobile viewport. size of the card exceeds the viewport.... see in codepen it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have done it , you can view it][1]

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/ZExJgmr
```